# Adding column values together

Tags: excel

Hello I would like to group the IDs in the first column and and you the amounts 
in the second column as shown below please.

Currently showing

[image: Currently showing]

Result I would like

[image: |The result I would like please]

Comment: Use a pivot table - that's what they do. ;)

Comment: Quite new to excel I'll look them up

Comment: Select the data, then on the Insert tab, choose Pivot table, make sure the range is correct in the dialog and press OK. Then drag ID to the row field area and Amount to the Values area.

Comment: `=SUMIF()` will also do here

Answer (score 0):

After Rorys recommendation I googled Pivot tables and sorted it out in less than 6 minutes watching the youtube video "Learn Pivot Tables in 6 Minutes (Microsoft Excel)".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qu-AK0Hv0b4